# Expansion of power series for $\frac{\ln(1-x)}{1+x}$

Tags: power-series

My Problem is to expand $f(x)=\dfrac{\ln(1-x)}{1+x}$ into a power series.

My Approach: from looking onto the Graphs of this function, i know, for rising x the y is falling towards Zero, without reaching it. but i don't think there is convergence for the series.

A power series has the scheme: $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n}\cdot x^{n}$ but im stuck in trying to convert $f(x)$ into a suitable sequence $a_{n}$.

Any hints?

Comment: We know power series expansion for [$ ln(1-x)$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=power+series+ln%281-x%29) and for [$1/(1+x)$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=power+series+1%2F%281%2Bx%29) too, just multiply those two power series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two series expansions, both for $|x|<1$, namely:

1) $\log(1+x)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{x^n}{n}$

2) $\frac{1}{1-x}=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}x^n$

Substituting $x$ with $-x$ doesn't change the convergence radius, hence you get

1') $\log(1-x)=-\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{x^n}{n}$

2') $\frac{1}{1+x}=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^nx^n$

Now multiply the two series together

$$\frac{\log(1-x)}{1+x}=(1-x+x^2-x^3+\ldots)\cdot(-x-\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{3}-\ldots)$$
$$=-x+\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{5x^3}{6}+\frac{7x^4}{12}-\frac{47x^5}{60}+ O(x^6)$$

Comment: how did you multiply that?

Comment: @ToralfWestström Same way you multiply polynomials, considering a series as a polynomyal with "infinite degree""